# Get total Post by author with MAP REDUCE

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

I'm trying to get the total posts for a given author.
My code (Doctrine Mongodb 1.2.x) :

```
 $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
               ->getManager();
    $qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('ngNearBundle:Posts');
    $count = $qb->select('active')
                    ->field('author')
                    ->equals($request->getSession()->get('userId'))
                    ->map('function() { emit("totalPosts", { count: 1 }); }')
                    ->reduce('function(k, vals) {
                                return vals.length;
                                            }'
                            )
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->execute()
                    ->toArray();
    var_dump($count);
```

I'm getting 16 posts when I should get more than 70 000 
How can I achieve this ? 
Thanks 

PS: 
Example of document:

```
    {
"_id" : ObjectId("5304981b9d922e182e2bc442"),
            "active" : 0,
            "author" : "52cb29b0211b6fd9248b456b",
            "contact" : "406-529-1966",
            "date" : ISODate("2014-02-19T11:39:51.027Z"),

            "title" : "Great day",
            "type" : 3
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to use map-reduce? This appears to be something the aggregate framework would be good at. What is your schema?

Comment: schemeless,author is just a field

Comment: Can you post a sample document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
return vals.length
```

change it to

```
return Array.sum(vals)
```

Also look here for reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

You can also use aggregation, something like below

```
db.collection.aggregate(
 {$match: {author: "52cb29b0211b6fd9248b456b"} },
 {$group: {_id:null, totalPosts: {$sum:1} } }
)
```

You will have to run this on your mongo console.

For more info look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/
and for doctorine mongo look here: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/issues/165

Comment: Someone said I don't need map reduce to calculate total post by author , do you agree ?

Comment: Yes, you could even do it using aggregation framework

Comment: Do you want me to post you the aggregation result using aggregation framework?

Comment: If possible , yes please , but also I want to know which way is the best practice, Map/reduce or aggregate ..
Because I only want to find the total posts for single user.

Comment: aggregation framework uses C++ under the hood so its faster than Map/Reduce.

Comment: Please check my actual response, I have edited it and added the example aggregation code.